# Inheritance annotation - Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two class as below. The "role" field is "duplicated".

```
@Entity(name="INHERITANCE_S1_EMPLOYEE_ANN")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int id = 0;
    private String name = null;
    private String role = null;

    public Employee(String name){
        setName(name);
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="EXECUTIVE")
public class Executive extends Employee{
    private String role = null;

    public Executive(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

My XML is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/JH</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">app</property>
        <property name="connection.password">app</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">0</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

How to correct this situation? Thanks a lot.

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated
>   column in mapping for entity:
>   com.madhusudhan.jh.advanced.inheritance.s1.Executive column: role
>   (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I do not want to delete the "role" filed in the class Executive, because they work well under XML mapping as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.madhusudhan.jh.advanced.inheritance.s1">
  <class name="Employee" table="INHERITANCE_S1_EMPLOYEE" discriminator-value="EMPLOYEE">
    <id  name="id" column="EMPLOYEE_ID">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="DISCRIMINATOR" type="string"/>

    <property name="name" column="NAME" />
    <subclass name="Executive" extends="Employee" discriminator-value="EXECUTIVE">
        <property name="role" column="ROLE"/>
    </subclass>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you check if you have role field in INHERITANCE_S1_EMPLOYEE_ANN class?

Answer (score 0):

`Executive` is extending `Employee`. So there's no need to redeclare `role` there. If you remove it from `Executive`, it would still work. It would just simply be inheriting the properties. Are you trying to connect them as two relational tables? e.g. `role` as `foreign key`

Comment: This is just an example from the book <Just Hibernate>. I am curious about how to correct the annotation to make it work. As you have seen, XML mapping does work well where there are two "role" fields.

Comment: From what I know, when I map two related tables I don't extend the parent. I just use `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany` annotations on the parent implementations in the child class with using `@JoinColumn( name = <foreign key> )` and `@JsonBackReference` and for the child implementation in the parent class I use `@ElementCollection` `@CollectionTable( name = <foreign key> )`